# Spring Boot actuator "system.cpu.usage" vs "process.cpu.usage"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer, spring-boot-2

I am using spring boot 2.3.2. With help of actuator, publishing the application metrics to metrics console. I would like to know what is the difference between `system.cpu.usage` and `process.cpu.usage` metrics polished by the actuator.

Answer (score 10):

Based on [source code](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/98bd8d3f2c31ced79c1fb6a21721172abc38bc21/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/system/ProcessorMetrics.java#L102)

- `system.cpu.usage` -- The recent cpu usage for the whole system
- `process.cpu.usage` -- The recent cpu usage for the Java Virtual Machine process

For more info about these metrics you can look at java doc of this bean [OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html)